# using swiper with ionic

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, swiper.js

i used ion-slides to scroll between 3 different images on the upper half of the screen, and now i'm using swiper (http://idangero.us/swiper/get-started/#.WMCuvjt942w) to implement a vertical scrolling menu that covers the lower half of the screen. but the problem is it overlaps the ion-slides and the ion-slides dont only shows one image instead of 3. is it possible to separate the upper and lower half screens? here's my code:

```
<ion-view title="Main Menu" id="page1">
<ion-content padding="true" class="has-header">
<ion-slides disable-side-menu-drag="" options="{'loop': false}" slider="slider1" delegate-handle="slider1" id="mainMenu-slider1" style="width:100%;height:200px;">
  <ion-slide-page id="mainMenu-slide24" style="background:url(&quot;img/card1.png&quot;) no-repeat center;background-size:cover;"><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>Amount:</ion-slide-page>
  <ion-slide-page id="mainMenu-slide25" style="background:url(&quot;img/card2.png&quot;) no-repeat center;background-size:cover;"><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>Amount:</ion-slide-page>
  <ion-slide-page id="mainMenu-slide26" style="background:url(&quot;img/card3.png&quot;) no-repeat center;background-size:cover;"><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>Amount:</ion-slide-page>
</ion-slides>
</ion-content>
 <ion-content>
 <div class="swiper-container">
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 1</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 2</div>
    </div>
</div>
</ion-content>
</ion-view>
```